# click on button in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am creating a button dynamically and place it in a placeholder as below

```
<asp:Button ID="generateTableSchema" runat="server" Text="Generate Table" OnClick="generate_Click" />

 protected void generate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
Button button = new Button();
button.Text = "Generate Table";
button.ID = "generateTable";
button.OnClick = hello();
PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(button);
}
```

but onclick event is not firing.

this is the error i  am getting

```
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(System.EventArgs)' is inaccessible due to its protection level
```

hello is as below...

```
public void hello()
    {
        Label1.Text = "heellllllllllo";
    }
```

What's wrong here????

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            button.Click += ButtonClick;
        }
    }
```

@Daren u mean like this...

Comment: Where do you call generate_Click ??

Comment: generate_Click is called on click of button....which is present on the webpage(not created dynamically)

Comment: That's your problem. you need to put your button creation INSIDE the Page_Load method, otherwise it won't be generated. Dynamic buttons with their handlers need to be created at page load.

Comment: See my update. You put the button code in the page load event

Comment: yeah, that will make sure it's generated every time - you need ALL your button code there though

Comment: you can just get rid of the `else { // }` though - it's not needed as you need it to run regardless

Comment: do u mean to say that...onclick on generate_click i make a button and put some value in the label which is hidden...and when i page reload and the button is created...it will assign the handler to that button

Comment: No.. Seriously, just copy the code i put in my answer.Create a page_load method. In here put your button code to create button, including handler. Its that simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are adding the button programmatic ally you have to add the event handler.

So this would work..

**EDIT** 
Wrapped the button INSIDE Page_Load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 Button button = new Button();
 button.Text = "Generate Table";
 button.ID = "generateTable";
 button.Click += hello;    /// THIS is the handler
 PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(button);
}
```

ButtonClick would be the name of your method.

```
    protected void hello(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     // ...
    }
```

Also, as you're generating this at runtime you need to makesure this gets called on postbacks too.

Comment: Where are you creating your button? It has to be in either load or init ideally. And it needs to be called on the postback too, otherwise the click handler won't exist

Comment: Added the method and signature for reference.

Comment: So in your code, put create your button in the page load event. This needs to be called when the user clicks your `button` so it can create the handler again. Do NOT put your `button` creation inside an `if (!isPostBack){}` otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Change `OnClick` to `click`  and `=` to `+=` and `hello()` to `hello` - just copy my code.

Comment: You must have something wrong, or it's in the wrong place. I promise you 100% this is how to do it. See other answers say the same too. Post the code where you are creating it.

Comment: thanks daren  it worked...i will post my code and select your answer...thanks for allowing me to eat ur head..

Comment: Excellent :) and you're welcome. We're here to help, we all know what it was like when we started.

Answer (score 1):

The `OnClick` is a protected method. You should use the event `Click`.

```
button.Click += new EventHandler(Click);

public void hello(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = "heellllllllllo";
}
```

By the way, make sure you create and add the control in every postback, otherwise the event won't work.

Comment: Below you said you're creating the button in a postback of another button. This is not enough. You need also to create it in page load event.

Comment: how to create in pageload event...do i need to copy the whole code where button is created in the pageload...

Comment: Don't copy it. Create a method that do it and call it in page load and in the original place.

Answer (score 1):

Change `button.OnClick = hello();` to:

```
button.Click += new EventHandler(hello);
```

And change the definition for `hello()` to:

```
protected void hello(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = "heeellllllo";
}
```

Comment: Are you re-creating your controls on every postback?

Comment: You need to re-create your button every postback unless it won't be there to send events on the next one. If you create it using a button click you need to set some flag or something and check that on every postback to see if it needs to be created again.

Answer (score 1):

The event is called [`Click`.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.click.aspx) You need to add the event handler with the correct signature:

```
button.Click += new EventHandler(hello);
```

and the signature is:

```
protected void hello(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // ...
}
```

[How to: Add an Event Handler Using Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743596.aspx)

Note that you need to recreate dynamical controls on every postback.

Comment: i tried this...but didn't help...instead page get reload...even i am checking autopostback in my pageload..

Answer (score 0):

You assigning the result of executing `hello()`.

Try assigning:

```
button.OnClick = hello;
```

-- edit--

apparantly, that does not clarify your error.

Add the handler to the event handler in stead:

```
button.Click += hello;
```

Comment: Won't help. It is a protected method.

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
        }
        else if(Page.IsPostBack && Label11.Text=="yes")
        {
            Button button = new Button();
            button.Text = "Generate Table";
            button.ID = "generateTable";
            button.Click += ButtonClick;
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(button);
        }
    }
```

setting

```
        Label11.Text = "yes";
```

in generate_click.

```
protected void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = "heeellllllo";
    }
```