# 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'Edit_Button_Click' is undefined

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, button

In my C# script, I make this button when the page loads.

```
    Button b = new Button();
    b.OnClientClick = "Edit_Button_Click(sender,e);";
```

The 'Edit_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)' function looks like this...

```
    protected void Edit_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btnSomeButton = sender as Button;
    btnSomeButton.Text = "I was clicked!";
}
```

But, when I click the button on the web form, before the code even gets to that function, I get an error that says '0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'Edit_Button_Click' is undefined'.
This is confusing to me because I didn't expect any JavaScript errors while I was writing my scripts in C#. I am new to designing webforms, so correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think I should be seeing anything related to JavaScript since the page language is in C#.

```
    <script runat = "server>

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    Button b = new Button();
            b.Text = "EDIT";
            b.ID = r.ID + "edit button";
            b.OnClick += Edit_Button_Click(sender, e);
    }

    protected void Edit_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btnSomeButton = sender as Button;
        btnSomeButton.Text = "I was clicked!";
    }

    </script>
```

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm using a .aspx webform page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing client-side and server-side events. Instead of

```
b.OnClientClick = "Edit_Button_Click(sender,e);";
```

(which assigns client-side handler for click event that happens in the browser) Do a

```
b.Click += Edit_Button_Click;
```

Which will assign your C# event handler that happens on the postback on server side.

Here's a basic example:

```
<script runat = "server">

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Button b = new Button();
       b.Text = "EDIT";
       b.ID = b.ID + "edit button";
       b.Click += Edit_Button_Click;
       form1.Controls.Add(b);
    }

    protected void Edit_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Button btnSomeButton = sender as Button;
       btnSomeButton.Text = "I was clicked!";
    }

</script>
```

Comment: That makes sense to me! When I write it like that, I get an error that says... 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(System.EventArgs)' is inaccessible due to its protection level. The Page_Load function and the Edit_Button_Click function are both protected. Should I change them? Is that dangerous?

Comment: Protected is fine and should work. Where do u declare your button and where function?

Comment: I declare the button in the Page_Load function. That function is the first function that runs. Then the Edit_Button_Click function should run once the user clicks the button.

Comment: Don't. Declare the button *inside* the Page_Load, but function Edit_Button_Click *outside* at the same level as Page_Load. I updated my answer with basic page example

Comment: Oh wait, maybe I wasn't clear. My button is declared inside of the Page_Load function and Edit_Button_Click is outside but at the same level as Page_Load (I think). Both of these functions are inside of a script. I updated my question to show what I mean.

Comment: I tried putting both of those functions inside of the public partial class that you have in your example, but when I do that, I get several errors that say... Cannot access a non-static member of outer type 'ASP.default_aspx' via nested type 'ASP.default_aspx.MyPage' These errors refer to members of other functions that I have in my page. Nothing to do with the button...
And I also get the original error.

Comment: @Torchedmuffinz sorry didn't know you used standalone page - please see my updated example in the answer above (a few things were missing)

Comment: I just found my answer! "Because you are adding the button programmatic ally you have to add the event handler." So I had to put this in... b.Click += Edit_Button_Click;                                                             Here is the link to the answer if you are interested! Thanks for your help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13456076/click-on-button-in-asp-net

Comment: @Torchedmuffinz Um... Isn't it what I said? Did you read my answer? Did you try it at all?

Comment: Oh wait, you're totally right. Sorry. I became confused because the error still existed when I put the functions inside of the public partial class. You're right, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Using OnClientClick in C# is creating a javascript function client-side called "Edit_Button_Click" but you are defining that function server-side (in your code-behind).

If you use OnClick it will call the server-side method.